# How to improve spacing between consecutive tcblistings?

Tags: listings, line-spacing, tcolorbox

I would like to have my SAS code with more or less the same distances between
the previous sentence and the following one. I did it putting it in a 
`tcolorbox` with
`before skip=0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt` and 
`after skip=4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt` (perhaps there are better
methods I don't know).

I don't want one `data` step be separated across pages 
(putting it within a
`tcolorbox` I can achieve that) but I want that two different 
`data` steps could be divided.

What I did works but there is too much space
between the end of one step and the start of another.
I know I can use `\vspace{-2pt}` to solve this, but there's no way to do it 
automatically?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=2.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{upquote}% per avere gli apici dritti nelle stringhe

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\tcbset{colback=blue!4!white,colframe=blue,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before skip = 16pt,
    parbox=false,
    before upper={\parindent0pt},
    }

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\stilestringa}{\color[rgb]{0.639,0.082,0.082}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandob}{\color{blue!50}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecommenti}{\color[RGB]{77,159,53}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilewarnings}{\color[RGB]{93,138,168}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stileerrori}{\color{red}\ttfamily}

\newcommand{\sasinline}[1]{\lstinline[style=saslst,    basicstyle=\ttfamily]!#1!}
\newcommand{\sasstringemph}[1]{\stilestringa \emph{#1}} 
\newcommand{\sasutente}[1]{\emph{#1}} 

\lstdefinestyle{saslst}{               
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    morekeywords=[1]{quit, proc, let, macro, mend},
    morekeywords=[2]{access, obs, firstobs, format, append, sort, sql, transpose, compare, in, when, otherwise, select},
    morecomment=[f]{*}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]{"},
    escapechar=|, 
    otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,\&,_,<,>=,=<,>,\%, =},
    keywordstyle={[1]\stilecomandoa},
    keywordstyle={[2]\stilecomandob},
    commentstyle=\stilecommenti,
    stringstyle=\stilestringa,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    keepspaces=true, 
    sensitive=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1
}

\newtcblisting{sas}{%
    listing only,
    before skip=0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    after skip=4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,  
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={style=saslst,            
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
        }
}

\begin{document} 
Here is a single \sasinline{data} step:
\begin{sas}
data classe;
set  sashelp.class;
when age=11;
run;
\end{sas}
Here there is too much space
between \sasinline{/* END OF ONE STEP */}
and \sasinline{/* START OF ANOTHER STEP */}:
\begin{sas}
data classe;
set  sashelp.class;
when age=11;
run;
/* END OF ONE STEP */
\end{sas}
\begin{sas}
/* START OF ANOTHER STEP */
data classe;
set  sashelp.class;
when age=11;
run;
\end{sas}
This is what I would like to achieve automatically:
\begin{sas}
data classe;
set  sashelp.class (obs=4); 
run;
/* END OF ONE STEP */
\end{sas}
\vspace{-2pt}\begin{sas}
/* START OF ANOTHER STEP */
data classe;
set  sashelp.class (obs=4, firstobs=10); 
run;
\end{sas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does  `before lower={\setlength{\parskip}{50pt}}` help? (or any other `...pt` value`)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately not, it remains too much space.

Comment: It was a guess only yet...

Comment: Quick and dirty: `code={\vspace{-2pt}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That works but affects also the position of the first step...

Comment: Yes, but if you draw the boxes with frames, you will see that the real cause is the display of the code inside of the boxes, in my point of view

Comment: Try negative values for `top` and `bottom`, but I think the real cause is `aboveskip` and `belowskip` from `listings`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've found a solution, if you would like to add another one with your explanation, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooo....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The message seems clear :):):)

Comment: Clear because I have nothing better to add, that's why I deleted my initial answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Christian Hupfer's advice, I think I've found a solution adding:

```
aboveskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
belowskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
```

to the `listing options`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=2.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{upquote}% per avere gli apici dritti nelle stringhe

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\tcbset{colback=blue!4!white,colframe=blue,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  %  before skip = 16pt,
    parbox=false,
    before upper={\parindent0pt},
    }

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\stilestringa}{\color[rgb]{0.639,0.082,0.082}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecomandob}{\color{blue!50}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilecommenti}{\color[RGB]{77,159,53}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stilewarnings}{\color[RGB]{93,138,168}\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\stileerrori}{\color{red}\ttfamily}

\newcommand{\sasinline}[1]{\lstinline[style=saslst,    basicstyle=\ttfamily]!#1!}
\newcommand{\sasstringemph}[1]{\stilestringa \emph{#1}} 
\newcommand{\sasutente}[1]{\emph{#1}} 

\lstdefinestyle{saslst}{               
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    aboveskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    belowskip=-4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    morekeywords=[1]{quit, proc, let, macro, mend},
    morekeywords=[2]{access, obs, firstobs, format, append, sort, sql, transpose, compare, in, when, otherwise, select},
    morecomment=[f]{*}, 
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]{"},
    escapechar=|, 
    otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,\&,_,<,>=,=<,>,\%, =},
    keywordstyle={[1]\stilecomandoa},
    keywordstyle={[2]\stilecomandob},
    commentstyle=\stilecommenti,
    stringstyle=\stilestringa,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    keepspaces=true, 
    sensitive=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1
}

\newtcblisting{sas}{%
    listing only,
%    before skip=0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
  %  after skip=4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
 %   code={\vspace{-2pt}},
 %   top=-2pt,
  %  bottom=-2pt,  
    enhanced,
    opacityfill=0,
    left=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={style=saslst,            
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
        }
}

\begin{document} 
\noindent Here is a single \sasinline{data} step:
\begin{sas}
data classe;
set  sashelp.class;
when age=11;
run;
\end{sas}
\noindent Here there is too much space
between \sasinline{/* END OF ONE STEP */}
and \sasinline{/* START OF ANOTHER STEP */}:
\begin{sas}
data classe;
set  sashelp.class;
when age=11;
run;
/* END OF ONE STEP */
\end{sas}
\begin{sas}
/* START OF ANOTHER STEP */
data classe;
set  sashelp.class;
when age=11;
run;
\end{sas}
\noindent This seems to work \textasciicircum\textasciicircum\textasciicircum
\end{document}
```

[image]